# How to access a website deployed on heroku from an iframe?

Tags: django, heroku, iframe

I created a [website](https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com) in `Django` that I deployed on `heroku`. It contains the following line in its `settings.py` file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

This means that it allows connection with any domain name. But when I try to access a site from an `iframe` on an `html` page from my localhost, I get the following error when loading my webpage:

**gkwhelps.herokuapp.com refused the connection.**

here is the code of my `iframe`:

```
<Iframe src="https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com"
                            width="450px"
                            height="450px"
                            />
```

I don't know why this happens because I authorized access to all hosts before deploying on `heroku`, I don't know if heroku has a policy about this which conditions the access to other hosts or the error comes from elsewhere. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the headers of your Heroku app, you will see the following:

`X-Frame-Options: DENY`

This means that Heroku refuses to accept iframe connections - hence the error you have received.

Comment: How to disable this

Comment: thanks again for the reply, this is my first time deploying an app to heroku, may i know where to find my app's security headers?

Comment: See the Heroku documentation on headers: https://blog.heroku.com/using-http-headers-to-secure-your-site#x-frame-options